# Is there a listener for dataLayer ready or present?

Tags: javascript, adobe, listener, analytics, tealium

We are trying to track elements of third party datalayer (Namogoo - journeyDataLayer) via Tealium sending to Adobe Analytics. Generally we would track it via mapping the variables to our own dataLayer and packing them with a pageview. However, Namogoo dataLayer only becomes present after the page loads which is why we are trying to send the data based on event. Is there a way to listen for that particular data layer to become ready/present on the page?

Kind regards,

Lu

Comment: Please provide some context here. What "datalayer"…?

Comment: Taking a stab into the dark here… would it help to mention the keyword *Google Analytics* at least once…?!

Comment: It's Adobe Analytics we are sending to and implementing via Tealium not the standard Adobe Launch way so Google Analytics may confuse things. Can mention Adobe if you prefer but Tealium should be the main focus point here. I apprecaite what you are doing and thank you for heping a newbie. :-)

Comment: Well, properly mention and tag *Adobe Analytics* or other relevant keywords then…!